# Java Spring Batch Embedded fields on model always null

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-batch

I'm having issues where the JdbcPagingItemReader can't pull in the values for fields that have been annotated with @Embedded.

For example:

```
@Entity
@Data
class Clothing {
  String name;

  @Embedded 
  Cost total;
}
```

During the batch job, the name will be correct, but the total is always null. How can I fix this?

Comment: Is `Cost` @Embeddable?  `Clothing` isn't an @Entity so not sure how this would work anyway.  Please add more code context and/or configuration.

Comment: Which `ItemReader` implementation are you using? How items are mapped to the domain type `Clothing` ?

Comment: Updated to have more context. Cost has Embeddable on the field. I'm able to save the object correctly into the database but upon running the batch job, some values are null. Fetching the records using a PagingAndSortingRepository works normally.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. See my answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

The `JdbcPagingItemReader` knows nothing about JPA mappings. It requires a `RowMapper` in order to map items to your domain type `Clothing`.

What you need to use is rather the `JpaPagingItemReader` which knows about `@Entity` annotated classes and how to map them to items.

Comment: Yes, I set the rowMapper to have a BeanPropertyRowMapper.

Comment: The `BeanPropertyRowMapper` is from Spring Framework and from its Javadoc it says: `The mapped target class must be a top-level class`. So I'm not sure that it will map "nested" types like `Cost` in your use case. You would probably need to provide your own `RowMapper` implementation.